# Not able to persist ACL users in ACL file in Redis

Tags: redis, acl

I am facing a peculiar issue.

In my redis.conf file, at first I enable a password authentication by setting:

```
requirepass admin
```

When I connect to Redis via CLI, I am required to authenticate myself before continuing any operation, so all good so far:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> get name
(error) NOAUTH Authentication required.
127.0.0.1:6379> auth admin
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> get name
"sahay"
```

Now, I try to create a ACL user by running:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> acl setuser nonadminuser on >generalpassword +@all -@dangerous ~*
OK
```

So far so good, now I want to persist this new user to a ACL file, so I run:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> acl save
(error) ERR This Redis instance is not configured to use an ACL file. You may want to specify users via the ACL SETUSER command and then issue a CONFIG REWRITE (assuming you have a Redis configuration file set) in order to store users in the Redis configuration.
```

This is also OK, since I have not set any configuration of aclfile in my redis.conf.

So, I stop my redis server and add this line in my redis.conf file:

```
aclfile /Ankit/redis_installation/redis-stable/acl_users.acl
```

I also create a **acl_users.acl** file in the above mentioned directory, because without it Redis throws an error that no such file exists.

Now comes the peculiar part. When I start redis, and connect to it via CLI, it doesn't ask me to authenticate! Even though

```
requirepass admin
```

is set in the redis.conf file. In fact, it throws error when I try to run a password.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> get name
"sahay"
127.0.0.1:6379> auth admin
(error) ERR AUTH <password> called without any password configured for the default user. Are you sure your configuration is correct?
```

Also, when I do an ACL save now (after creating the new user), that new user is created and persisted in acl file but the strange thing is default user is stored with "nopass"

Why is default user configured as nopass even when config file has a requirepass clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**requirepass** is not compatible with ACL feature. If you config with ACL rules, **requirepass** is ignored. That's why you can operate Redis as the default user without sending `auth` command.

With ACL feature, you need to explicitly set a rule for default user.

```
user default on +@all ~* >password
```